# Swift Custom Tableview Cell with UITableViewCellStyle

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to make a custom table view cell.

If I do this:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var cellBackgroundImage : UIImageView!
}
```

And:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.cellBackgroundImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    cell.cellBackgroundImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.cellBackgroundImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    let event = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)

    self.configureCell(cell, withEvent: event)

    return cell
}
```

I obtain a white rounded cell background. Easy. And I can use the original `cell.textLabel.text`.

Perfect.

But, if I want to do something more complex:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell") as? TableViewCell

    cell?.cellBackgroundImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    cell?.cellBackgroundImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell?.cellBackgroundImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    self.configureCell(cell!, withObject: object)
}
```

And at the same time to use the original table view properties as `UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle` and `cell.accessoryView`, the app crashes or shows the wrong output.

THIS MEANS THAT I MUST USE A FULL CUSTOM CELL WITH MORE OUTLETS TO REPLACE THE ORIGINAL ELEMENTS AS **UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle** and **cell.accessoryView** ???

I will express it in a different way:

Can I use a custom tableview cell only for one purpose (like the rounded background) and use the original elements such as the subtitle style and the accesory view?

In afirmative case, how?

Comment: FYI - `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell` will never return `nil` (assuming it is registered correctly).

Comment: What is the crash that you're getting? And please show what you mean by "use the original table view properties" (ie your code).

Comment: The second way you didn't return anything though. `self.configureCell(cell!, withObject: object)` is causing the crash because as the discussion above, `var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell`
can not be nil which means `cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle` will not be executed at all.